# simplexml_load_file - failed to open stream: Network is unreachable

Tags: php, rss

I am having an issue getting my blog RSS feed to display on my website. This code runs fine locally but when I upload it to the server it throws errors.

The errors I am getting are:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://harrietlawrie.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss): failed to open stream: Network is unreachable in /srv/disk3/1425834/www/harrietlawrie.co.uk/blog.php on line 47

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://harrietlawrie.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss" in /srv/disk3/1425834/www/harrietlawrie.co.uk/blog.php on line 47

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /srv/disk3/1425834/www/harrietlawrie.co.uk/blog.php on line 51
```

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
$i = 0; // counter
$url = "http://harrietlawrie.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss"; // url to parse
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url); // XML parser

// RSS items loop

foreach($rss->channel->item as $item) {
  if ($i < 10) { // parse only 10 items

    $pubdate = date('D, d M Y H:i:s ', strtotime($item->pubDate));
    print '<a href="'.$item->link.'"><h2>'.$item->title.'</h2></a>
    <div><b>'. $pubdate.'</b></div>
    <br>
    <div>'.$item->description.'</div>
    <hr>';
  }

$i++;
}    

?>
```

I have checked for `allow_url_fopen = On` in the PHP.ini and it is there.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I would go about fixing this?

Thank-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

It was a configuration issue with my webhost, I found this in the FAQ:

> 15. I cannot connect to remote scripts, RSS feeds or use cURL on my website?
>
> The outgoing connections are disabled by default on all accounts for
> security reasons, however they can be enabled for paid accounts from
> Hosting Settings section. So all you need to do is go to your panel
> Hosting Settings section look for "Firewall Options" and click on the
> "Enable" button.

Source: FreeHostingEu - http://freehostingeu.runhosting.com/faq.html